# Finding a potential function - vector fields

Tags: vector-fields

Let F be the vector function - $\overrightarrow{F} = (\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})$

We know that F is conservative on every path that doesnt encircle the point $(0,0)$

Calculating it's potential function gave me - $\phi = arctan(\frac{x}{y})$
the problem is with the points $(x,0)$,

what can we say about those points? the potential is not defined there.

How can I, for example, calculate the work on a linear route from (0,1) to (1,0)? I would like to say $\phi(0,1) - \phi(1,0)$ but $\phi(1,0)$ is not defined.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't define the potential function everywhere, only on a region that doesn't wind around the pole at $ ( 0 , 0 ) $.  You can use $ \arctan ( y / x ) $ on the region where $ x > 0 $ and separately on the region where $ x < 0 $; you can also use $ \operatorname { arccot } ( x / y ) = \pi / 2 - \arctan ( x / y ) $ on the region where $ y > 0 $ and separately on the region where $ y < 0 $.  You can also add a constant to any of these.  Altogether, these cover the entire region except $ ( 0 , 0 ) $, and where they overlap, they differ by constants (multiples of $ \pi $, in fact).  So if you want to cross the boundary of one of them, then you can switch to another one, adding the appropriate constant.  In this way, you can patch together a single potential function to use on your entire path, as long as it doesn't wind around the origin.

In particular, since $ \arctan ( y / x ) $ agrees with $ \operatorname { arccot } ( x / y ) $ in the first quadrant, you can use those function (with no need to even add a constant) to cover your entire line segment.  To be explicit about the combined function, it's $$ \phi ( x , y ) : = \cases { \arctan ( y / x ) & for \( x > 0 \), \\ \operatorname { arccot } ( x / y ) & for \( y > 0 \). } $$  (And you can extend this into the 4th quadrant, but not *all* the way around.)  In particular, $ \phi ( 1 , 0 ) = \arctan ( 0 / 1 ) = 0 $ and $ \phi ( 0 , 1 ) = \operatorname { arccot } ( 0 / 1 ) = \pi / 2 $, so the integral is $ \pi / 2 - 0 = \pi / 2 $ (which I think you knew it had to be).

Comment: Here if we take $M$ and $N$ as component function of $F$ then $M_y =N_x$ On $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$. So Mdx+Ndy is exact and by necessary and sufficient condition we have potential function on  $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}.$ which is not the case . So does it mean that while proving sufficient part of exact ness we need domain D simply connected?

Comment: @MeetPatel :  Yes, that's exactly right.  The term for $ M \, \mathrm d x + N \, \mathrm d y $ when $ \partial M / \partial y = \partial N / \partial Y $ is **closed,** and the theorem is that while any differentiable exact form must be closed, a closed $ 1 $-form only has to be exact if its domain is simply connected (or more generally if each connected component of its domain is simply connected).

Comment: Another theorem is that any closed form must be locally exact: for each point in its domain, for some neighbourhood of that point in the domain, the restriction of the form to that neighbourhood is exact.  In the example here, you could take the neighbourhood to consist of almost the entire plane, leaving out only a single closed ray (half-line) from the origin, but you can't do more than that.